# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.CurrentPage_Call.<init>: line 7, column 1

Tags: apex, visualforce

Apex:

```
public class CurrentPage_Call {
    public Account acc{set;get;}
    public String acctId{set;get;}
    public CurrentPage_Call(){
        acc=new Account();
        acctId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        acc=[select id,name,phone,Active__c,SLAExpirationDate__c,SLA__c,rating from Account where Id =: acctId];        
    }
    public ApexPages.pageReference save(){

        ApexPages.pageReference p=new ApexPages.pageReference('/'+acc.Id);
        update acc;
        return p;
    }

}
```

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="CurrentPage_Call">
    <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Current page record">
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:inputField value="{!acc.rating}"/>
               <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Active__c}"/>
             <apex:inputField value="{!acc.SLAExpirationDate__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.SLA__c}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.phone}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>  
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>    

    </apex:form>
```

Comment: Why are you not just using a standard controller here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will happen when you load this page without providing an `id` URL parameter. This query

```
    acc=[select id,name,phone,Active__c,SLAExpirationDate__c,SLA__c,rating from Account where Id =: acctId];
```

returns no results because `acctId` is `null`. That results in a `QueryException` any time it's evaluated in a single-Sobject context.

Answer (score 0):

1 of 2 things are happening:

1. As David said, you might not be passing in an `id` parameter to your URL.
2. If you are passing in an Id, then you're passing an Id that is invalid. Maybe that id is bad, or the record has been deleted.

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm), QueryExceptions are thrown when:

> Any problem with SOQL queries, such as assigning a query that returns no records or more than one record to a singleton sObject variable.